# Express session create new session every request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I been search a lot and dont found solutions,
when I send request in postman everything goes well
but in my react app every request I send i get new session and I lossing my User info (using passport)

**there is my backend session configuration:**

```
app.use(cors({ 
  credentials: true, 
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods:['GET','POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
}));
//SESSION CONFIGURATION
const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: connection,
  collection: 'sessions'
})

  const sessionConfig = {
  store: sessionStore,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true, secure: false} 
};
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
```

**there is my axios configuration (fontend):**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
    withCredentials: true
});
```

I really exhausted from this problem need some help thanks in advance

**UPDATED**

problem not solved but I see that my client side dont store any coockie in the browser and I get the coockie in the auth response

Comment: What about setting the res.headers- `app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type")
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH")
    next();
})` . It might help store the cookie.